# Can we use activities in action bar class ,using one activity for each tab not fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, fragment

Can we use activities in action bar class, using one activity for each tab rather than fragments? If yes then how its possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to launch new activities when user clicks on action bar items? Yes, this is possible. Launching new activities make sense only with buttons though, not with tabs. Why not use fragments?

Comment: @YuriyKulikov ,what is the advantage of using fragment for each tab rather than using activities, i wanna use activities beacuse these are much more easier to tackle rather than fragments ? am i ryt?

Comment: Hi, advantage is that fragment is so much more flexible. And they are not that much harder to understand. Think of a fragment as an activity, but  which occupies only a part of screen (a window). You can have an activity which shows only one fragment if you want. Later you can easily put the same fragment into a tab.

Comment: How can you say Activity is much more easier to tackle rather than fragment? Prove it.